# Topology on compactly supported smooth functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, category-theory, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I'm confused by a set of lecture notes I'm reading and would like help in understanding what's going on. First, there is the following nice theorem.

**Theorem.** The topology of a locally convex space is the *limit* topology w.r.t the collection of seminorms obtained as Minkowski functionals associated to a local basis of $0$ consisting of convex, balanced, open sets.

Then the notes go on to define $C^\infty _c(U)$ as a *colimit*, with a colimit topology:

$C^\infty _c(U)$ is defined to be the colimit in $\mathsf{Top}$
$$C_c^\infty (U)=\varinjlim _{K\subset U}C^\infty (K),\;\;\;\;K\text{ compact}$$
The topology on this colimit is the *<s>co</s>limit topology w.r.t to the following family of seminorms*
$$p_{K,n}(f)=\sup \left\{|\partial ^\alpha f(x)|:x\in K,|\alpha|\leq n \right\}.$$

What bugs me is the "lack of uniformity" here, since we sometimes topologize with the limit topology w.r.t the family of seminorms and sometimes with the colimit topology.

> Isn't there some uniform approach to topologizing these spaces?

Comment: If you declare an absolutely convex set $V \subseteq C_c^\infty(U)$ a $0$-neighbourhood if, for all $K$ there are $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\varepsilon$ such that  $V\cap C^\infty(K) \supset \lbrace f\in C^\infty(K): |\partial^\alpha f(x) |\le \varepsilon$ for all $|\alpha|\le n\rbrace$ -- then the (locally convex) colimit topology is the limit topology.

Comment: @Jochen I don't understand your comment. Can you post a more detailed version as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Functional Analysis, one often speaks of *projective limits* (limits in the category LCS of locally convex spaces) and *inductive limits* (colimits in LCS). In the latter case one has to be careful as colimits in TOP usually differ from those in LCS. What you state as a theorem says that every locally convex space is a projective limit of seminormed spaces.

To apply this little theorem to $C_c^\infty(U)$ one needs a locally convex topology and in my comment I gave a description of a system of $0$-neighbourhoods of such a topology, explicitely a subset $A$ of $C_c^\infty(U)$ is open if, for every $g\in A$ the set $A-g$ contains an absolutely convex set $V$ such that, for every compact $K\subseteq U$ there are $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $V\supset \lbrace f\in C^\infty(K): |\partial^\alpha f(x)|\le \varepsilon$ for all $|\alpha|\le n\rbrace$. This is not very handy for concrete calculations but it is quite easy to see that the topology satisfies the universal property a colimit should have: A *linear* map $C_c^\infty(U) \to X$ (where $X$ is any locally convex space) is continuous if and only if all restrictions $T|_{C^\infty(K)}$ are continuous.

Contrary to that theorem, it is not true that every locally convex space is an inductive limit of seminormed spaces. Such space are called *bornological*.

There is also a caegory BOR of vector spaces endowed with a so-called bornology (a system of bounded sets). In this category, colimits are much easier but there is a high price to pay: the Hahn-Banach theorem is no longer true in BOR.

Comment: Last sentence of the first paragraph - in which category is the projective limit taken? Also, I'm still confused. It seems then that the topology on $C^\infty _c(U)$ is the colimit topology w.r.t inclusions, and is also the limit topology w.r.t the seminorms $p_{K,n}$, contrary to what I wrote in the body of the question. Is this correct?

Comment: Systematically, the (projective) limit should be taken in LCS. However, it coincides with the limit in TOP.  And you are right: the colimit topology of $C_c^\infty(U)$ equals the limit topology w.r.t. $P_{K,n}$.

Comment: What kind of (co)limits does the forgetful functor $\mathsf{LCS}\rightarrow \mathsf{Top}$ reflect?